# I am having a problem with my APEX InvocableMethod returning an error when run through process builder

Tags: salesforce, apex, processbuilder

I have created an invocable method to run through Process builder. Although the class works when triggered with some changes, I get an error when running it through the process builder. From what I have determined, it is happening because the call out isn't run asynchronously.

That being said, I have tried to separate the classes and make one a future call out but I cannot figure out how to pass the three strings I have from the invocable class to my call out class.

Any help would be great!

```
public class SendText {

        public class DataWrapper {

        @InvocableVariable(label='Correspondence Name' required=true)
        public String CorrespondenceName;
        @InvocableVariable(label='Phone Number' required=true)
        public String PhoneNumber;
        @InvocableVariable(label='Text Message' required=true)
        public String textMessage;

    }

    @InvocableMethod(label='Send Text Message')
    public static void callSendTextMessage (List<DataWrapper> passedData) {

        for (DataWrapper dw: passedData) {

        //Basic Info needed to send request
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://api.podium.com/api/v2/conversations');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        request.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
        request.setHeader('Authorization', 'API Key');

        //Create the 4 required fields for Podium
        Map<String, String> message = new Map<String, String>{
            'customerPhoneNumber' => dw.PhoneNumber,
            'message' => dw.textMessage,
            'locationId' => '49257',
            'customerName' => dw.CorrespondenceName
        };

        String messageJson = JSON.serialize(message);
        System.debug(messageJson);

        request.setBody(messageJson);
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

        // Parse the JSON response
        if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
            System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
               response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
        } else {
            System.debug(response.getBody());
        }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you tried `Queueable Apex` but this is how I do it, give this a shot:

```
public class SendText {

    public class DataWrapper {

        @InvocableVariable(label='Correspondence Name' required=true)
        public String CorrespondenceName;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Phone Number' required=true)
        public String PhoneNumber;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Text Message' required=true)
        public String textMessage;

    }

    @InvocableMethod(label='Send Text Message')
    public static void callSendTextMessage (List<DataWrapper> passedData) {

        Id jobId = System.enqueueJob(new TextMessaeQueueable(passedData));
        System.debug('Text messages job Id => ' + jobId);
    }

    private class TextMessaeQueueable implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {

        private List<DataWrapper> wrappedData;

        public TextMessaeQueueable(List<DataWrapper> passedData) {
            this.wrappedData = passedData
        }

        public void execute(QueueableContext context) {

            for (DataWrapper dw: this.wrappedData) {

                //Basic Info needed to send request
                Http http = new Http();
                HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
                request.setEndpoint('https://api.podium.com/api/v2/conversations');
                request.setMethod('POST');
                request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                request.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
                request.setHeader('Authorization', 'API Key');

                //Create the 4 required fields for Podium
                Map<String, String> message = new Map<String, String>{
                    'customerPhoneNumber' => dw.PhoneNumber,
                    'message' => dw.textMessage,
                    'locationId' => '49257',
                    'customerName' => dw.CorrespondenceName
                };

                String messageJson = JSON.serialize(message);
                System.debug(messageJson);

                request.setBody(messageJson);
                HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

                // Parse the JSON response
                if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
                    System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
                        response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
                } else {
                    System.debug(response.getBody());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```